# If with condition and extract 4 character from a value

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains column$date as 102009 so i would like to extract the year as 2009

Comment: "Please fix or write my code for me" is not a question. What is your question?

Comment: You should [edit] your question so these details are in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `substring` function in R along with `ifelse`.

```
columns$date <- substring(as.character(columns$date), 3)
columns$cases<- ifelse(columns$cases == 1, "C1",
                ifelse(columns$cases == 2, "C2",
                ifelse(columns$cases == 3, "C3", "CDEF"))))
```

Comment: Thank you @akash87